# android trianglish shape drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

I would like to achieve something like this:

[image]

This is my code. I unsuccessfully played with different attributes but nothing helped so far.
This is what I get. Colors are not important here

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="-45%"
        android:pivotY="-45%">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke android:color="@color/gray" android:width="1dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/gray" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="100%">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke android:color="@color/gray" android:width="1dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/occupationGreen" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Comment: There's a shouting monkey in my head which doesn't stop crying: "VectorDrawable!"...

Comment: I don't understand you. You want to say this is not possible or that is not right approach?

Comment: Ooo, vector drawables :)

Comment: I think it's much easier. And I do mean **much**.

Comment: I can see it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solution: (vector drawables)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:height="100dp"
android:width="100dp"
android:viewportHeight="100"
android:viewportWidth="100" >
<group
    android:name="triableGroup">
    <path
        android:name="triangle"
        android:fillColor="#00C717"
        android:pathData="m 100,0 l 0,100 -100,0 z" />
</group>
```

you cannot use @color references for colors  otherwise it will work only for L+